# do we really need port for a headless service?

Tags: kubernetes

It might be a question based on curiosity which couldn't find help on google.

Consider this part of the yaml for a headless service:

```
ports:
 - port: abcd  --> this line
```

My doubt is when the cluster-ip for a headless service is already none (as it is a set of pods that it points to), what is the use of having the port for a service? The dns record from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) for services states that:

> “Headless” (without a cluster IP) Services are also assigned a DNS A record for a name of the form my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local. Unlike normal Services, this resolves to the set of IPs of the pods selected by the Service. Clients are expected to consume the set or else use standard round-robin selection from the set.

Hence, if the dns that is allocated to the headless services is solely used to have endpoints into the pods, is there any use-case of having the port functionality in a headless service?

I have seen issues that people have faced while excluding the port value from the definition of headless service ([here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55158)). This seems to have been fixed. But then, do we really have a use-case for the port functionality of a headless service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But then, do we really have a use-case for the port functionality of a headless service?

IMHO, yes: because the very idea of a `Service` is not "a random IP address" -- otherwise it would be called `DHCPIPAddress`. The idea of a `Service` in kubernetes is that you can consume some network functionality using one or more tuples of `(address, protocol, port)` just like in the non-kubernetes world.

So it can be fine if you don't care about the port of a headless `Service`, in which case toss in `ports:\n- port: 80\n` and call it a draw, but the **benefit** of a headless `Service` is to expose an extra-cluster network resource in a manner that kubernetes itself cannot manage. I used that very trick to help us transition from one cluster to another by creating a headless `Service`, whose name was what the previous `Deployment` expected, with the named `ports:` that the previous `Deployment` expected, but pointing to an IP that I controlled, not within the SDN.

Doing that, all the traditional kubernetes `kube-dns` and `$(SERVICE_THING_HOST)` and `$(SERVICE_THING_PORT)` injection worked as expected, but abstracted away the fact that said `_HOST` temporarily lived outside the cluster.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I have just one doubt: `with the named ports: what the previous deployment expected`, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: _with the named ports_ because our `Service` (`rabbitmq` in this specific case) had a named port: `{"ports": [{"name": "amqp", "port": 5672, "targetPort": "amqp"}]}`, k8s declared `$(RABBITMQ_SERVICE_PORT_AMQP)` for me, allowing the existing Pods to use the new foreign IP and its named target port with no changes to the `PodSpec`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and here is the answer: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20488#issuecomment-178682638

citation:

The concept of "port" being different from "targetPort" doesn't apply to headless services. The port translation is happening as part of the layer-4 load-balancing, but headless really means "no load-balancer".
...
**That is why we require X and Y to be the same in headless services.**